# android mediaRecorder.setAudioSource failed

Tags: android, media-player, voice, gfx

I have android G1 firmware 1.6, I am trying to record voice from the app with the follow code.

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();
```

my manifest.xml has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

I got:

```
09-23 14:41:05.531: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1718): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-23 14:41:05.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1718): java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
09-23 14:41:05.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1718):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
```

how do I record voice properly?

Comment: Time to change the accepted answer...

Answer (score 127):

Open "`AndroidManifest.xml`" ->

**add**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: Geeze, I wish there were some uniformity in the permission names. `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` is great, if there's also `android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO`, but there's not, there's `android.permission.CAMERA` which leads obviously to `android.permission.MICROPHONE` which of course doesn't exist. Curses.

Comment: Also watch casing. In Android Studio it automatically entered the uppercase name of the constant "ANDROID_PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO", but that isn't working!

Comment: If you forgot this, you may have also forgotten `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to store the audio file.

Comment: please can you confirm the location of this manifest file on the file system and also if this is still the case for Android 7.1?

Comment: or just accept this permission if running on Android > 6.0 ;)

Comment: worked for me.  For anyone else, you can tell it's working because your device should ask for permission to record audio while using this app.
Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

I know this is a very old question but in Android Marshmallow you have to go on "Settings > Apps > Your App > Permissions" and enble Microphone permission.

Comment: Information on how to request individual permissions at runtime:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 13):

If you are running on Android M, then you need to request permissions to record audio on first run. To accomplish this, ask the user if you can record audio when the application starts:

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 29;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    } else {
        Log.d("Home", "Already granted access");
        initializeView(v);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("Home", "Permission Granted");
                initializeView(v);
            } else {
                Log.d("Home", "Permission Failed");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "You must allow permission record audio to your mobile device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
        // Add additional cases for other permissions you may have asked for
    }
}
```

Comment: Change **READ** constant to **WRITE**.

Answer (score 6):

For API 23+, check audio record permission in both Manifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />` and in Java Code

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(cnt, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(cnt, arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        ),0)
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

IMPORTANT - 
during the last few hours I tried to figure out how to check if the MIC is caught by a different application or not. I noticed that if 2 application address to MediaRecorder at the same time a RuntimeException will be tossed and you won't be able to use the mic, unless you restart your device (!!)
I don't know if it's the best solution but it worked for me.
perhaps it will save some of you a few hours some day..

```
private void validateMicAvailability() throws MicUnaccessibleException {
    AudioRecord recorder =
        new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT, 44100);
    try{
        if(recorder.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED ){
            throw new MicUnaccessibleException("Mic didn't successfully initialized");
        }

        recorder.startRecording();
        if(recorder.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING){
            recorder.stop();
            throw new MicUnaccessibleException("Mic is in use and can't be accessed");
        }
        recorder.stop();
    } finally{
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact problem, this solved it for me:

On the device you use for debugging go to Settings -> Apps -> {your app}.
Then make sure all the app's permissions (in this case Audio Recording and Writing External Storage) are permitted.

Apprarently when installing an app not via Google Play Store you don't get asked to grant permissions and on some phones this will result in your debugging app not getting some permissions granted.

Check this even if some permissions in the manifest file are getting recognised (such as internet access) because for me some worked and some got automatically blocked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

For API 23+ you need to request the read/write permissions even if they are already in your manifest.

```
// Check for permissions
int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

// If we don't have permissions, ask user for permissions
if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    }; 
    int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        getActivity(),
        PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
        REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please request `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` permission dynamically for Marshmallow and above version.

Answer (score 1):

That looks correct.  Make sure other other applications aren't already using the MIC.  Perhaps give the phone a restart and try again.

Comment: If I can use it twice in parallel? For example my CAMCODER used for life audio&Video stream and I need to record it to my device in parallel, with video i don't have any problems but audio recording to one of results.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me

```
 mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
 mRecorder.reset();
 mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a Cyanogenmod-User I had to

1. make sure the permissions are defined in the manifest (android-studio)
2. make sure the privacy guard allowed the app to access the microphone (on the device)
3. make sure the android system had set the permissions under `Settings` --> `Apps` --> Select your app --> `Permissions` --> Check all permissions (should be the ones requested by the manifest) (on the device)

After that recoding worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this code it helps you a lot and its understandable .....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Button start, stop, play,stop_play;
    String FileName="";
    File outfile ;

    public static final int request_code = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start_main);
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_main);
        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play_main);
        stop_play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_playstop_main);

        if (checkPermissionFromDevice()){

            start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FileName= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+
                            UUID.randomUUID()+"AudioFile.3gp";

                    SetupMediaRecorder();

                    try {
                        mRecorder.prepare();
                        mRecorder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    start.setEnabled(false);
                    stop.setEnabled(true);
                    play.setEnabled(false);
                    stop_play.setEnabled(false);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"recording....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mRecorder.stop();
                    play.setEnabled(true);
                    start.setEnabled(true);
                    stop.setEnabled(false);
                    stop_play.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"recording stoped....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileName);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    start.setEnabled(false);
                    stop.setEnabled(false);
                    play.setEnabled(false);
                    stop_play.setEnabled(true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"playing..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            stop_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    SetupMediaRecorder();
                    start.setEnabled(true);
                    stop_play.setEnabled(false);
                    play.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });

        }
        else {

            requestPermissionFromDevice();
        }





    }

    private void SetupMediaRecorder() {
        mRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(FileName);
    }

    private void requestPermissionFromDevice() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                request_code);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case request_code:
            {
                if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"permission granted...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"permission denied...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissionFromDevice() {
        int storage_permission= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int recorder_permssion=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
    return storage_permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && recorder_permssion == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I moved it to another thread. Everything works.

Here's a code:

```
new Thread(() -> {
    mediaRecorder.reset();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/audiorecordtest.3gp");
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            //do something here
            mediaRecorder.stop();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Audio","unable to prepare");
        }

}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion might look stupid, but it worked for me :)

Try giving permission as a nested tag. I believe there is an xml parsing issue somewhere 
with android packaging library.

Comment: whats your point about giving nested tag ,may be you are talking about the <uses-permission>, on Manifest

Answer (score 0):

it work for me :-

Ask for permission after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the android system had set the permissions on the device, should be the ones requested by the manifest:

- under Settings --> Apps --> Select your app --> Permissions --> Check all permissions in on

Answer (score -16):

Change

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" ></uses-permission>
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Those evaluate to the same thing. The first is self-closing.

Comment: @xpq What the hell you are doing here, this is same