# Audio recording problem in Android

Tags: android

Since many days I am trying to develop the audio recording application in android but it shows setAudioSource fail exception, can any one help me to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

just see this question ,,,,and try with that answer. i hope you got answer from that

[android mediaRecorder.setAudioSource failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3782786/607853)