# Forceclose error due to recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

Tags: android

I am creating a sound recorder app, I've been googling the whole day and I've found a few codes that can be used to record audio. but every time I run the code my application hits a force close error and shuts down.
The code I've found is as follow

```
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); ***<== ERROR***
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/sample.3gp");

    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm using Android API 2.1

Comment: Please post the error in the stack trace. You can find it in the LogCat view of eclipse or by running the `adb logcat` by yourself...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android mediaRecorder.setAudioSource failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782786/android-mediarecorder-setaudiosource-failed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best example you can find is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#capture

I hope you tested it on a phone, because:

> Note that the emulator doesn't have hardware to capture audio or video, but actual mobile devices are likely to provide these capabilities, accessible through the MediaRecorder class.

And have a look at this:

```
/*
 * The application needs to have the permission to write to external storage
 * if the output file is written to the external storage, and also the
 * permission to record audio. These permissions must be set in the
 * application's AndroidManifest.xml file, with something like:
 *
 * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 */
```

Comment: Thnkyou very much, setting the permissions did the trick... the code doesn't show any errors however i dont know where the file that i recorded is stored or is it even being recorded at all.... any idea where "/sdcard/sample.3gp" would be,, and another thing im a student so i don't have an android mobile i can only test it on the emulator... any help would be greatly appreciated ... thnks in advance...

Comment: On a phone you can access the sdcard with a File-Explorer (there are lots of apps in the market), currently I have no idea how this is simulated in the emulator. I see no way to test the recording without a phone at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
 mRecorder.reset();
 mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

This is same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782786/android-mediarecorder-setaudiosource-failed/23191688#23191688) and I wrote the same answer there.

Answer (score 0):

**Provide permission in Manifest file:-**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```