# RuntimeException: start failed in AudioRecording

Tags: android

Ham doing audio recording in my project. The problem is ham getting runtime exception in my project.

```
 12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at com.android.audio.AudioRecordActivity.startRecording(AudioRecordActivity.java:80)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at com.android.audio.AudioRecordActivity.access$1(AudioRecordActivity.java:67)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at com.android.audio.AudioRecordActivity$3.onClick(AudioRecordActivity.java:138)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3460)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13955)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-02 14:58:47.145: E/AndroidRuntime(22802):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

when I debug and I'm getting the error in this particular line of code:

recorder.start();

My source code is as follows

```
 package com.android.audio;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AudioRecordActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP = ".3gp";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 = ".mp4";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
    File file;
    private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
    private int currentFormat = 0;
    private int output_formats[] = { MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4, MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP };
    private String file_exts[] = { AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4, AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP }; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);
    setFormatButtonCaption();
}

    private void setButtonHandlers() {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFormat)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }

    private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
            ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
    }

    private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
            enableButton(R.id.btnStart,!isRecording);
            enableButton(R.id.btnFormat,!isRecording);
            enableButton(R.id.btnStop,isRecording);
    }

    private void setFormatButtonCaption(){
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFormat)).setText(getString(R.string.audio_format) + " (" + file_exts[currentFormat] + ")");
    }

    private String getFilename(){

            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

            if(!file.exists()){
                    file.mkdirs();
            }




            return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
    }


    private void startRecording(){
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();

            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());

            recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
            recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

            try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private void stopRecording(){
            if(null != recorder){
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();

                    recorder = null;
            }
    }

    private void displayFormatDialog(){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            String formats[] = {"MPEG 4", "3GPP"};

            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_format_title))
                       .setSingleChoiceItems(formats, currentFormat, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    currentFormat = which;
                                    setFormatButtonCaption();

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                       })
                       .show();
    }

    private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    AppLog.logString("Error: " + what + ", " + extra);
            }
    };

    private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    AppLog.logString("Warning: " + what + ", " + extra);
            }
    };

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch(v.getId()){
                            case R.id.btnStart:{
                                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                                    enableButtons(true);
                                    startRecording();

                                    break;
                            }
                            case R.id.btnStop:{
                                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                                    enableButtons(false);
                                    stopRecording();

                                    break;
                            }
                            case R.id.btnFormat:{
                                    displayFormatDialog();

                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }; 


}
```

Comment: have you provided the permissions

Comment: ya thanks i forgot about the permission. i added this permission now its working <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: illegal state exception arises not bcoz of permissions but due to the way u handle media player. Go through documentations on various methods like prepare,stop,start,release etc. This is the problem.

Comment: Please look at my answer here :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33482754/4700721 I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

As described in the [android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) you need to set the following permissions in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

If you set these up, it should not throw that exception.

**Edit after comments:** If you get a `FileNotFound` Exception on `mRecorder.prepare();`, I'd assume it's because the file you reference in `mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);` does not exist, or is initialized incorrectly. Perhaps if you try to log the filename string you can see if it looks like the way you intended.

Comment: plz help me to find out what is the problem ham getting illegalstateexception even if i add permission

Comment: mRecorder.prepare(); ham getting error here after debugging and got filenotfound exception

Comment: why media recorder is not getting strated

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please set the answer as accepted if it helps you!

Comment: now i debbuged and saw i have the file in the path i.e. in sdcard location but when it comes to  mRecorder.start(); ham getting exception as 12-02 13:57:38.994: E/AndroidRuntime(20580): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.

Comment: In response to your attempt to edit my answer, please edit your question instead, to help me and others answer it. Stack trace would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I was using:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and it showed me error.
Then I changed it to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Looks stupid, but surprisingly it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

and you may get the solution,
you have to add  **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    MediaPlayer mp;

    File mPath;
    String datavideo = "/sdcard/musicfiles.mp4";
    String datamusic = "/sdcard/musicfileone.mp3";

    String urlString = "http://192.168.1.92/Stream/song.mp3";

    String urlVodeo = "http://192.168.1.92/Stream/Wildlife.mp4";

    Button btnVideo, btnAudio, btnViewVideo;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStoreVideo);
        btnAudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstoreAudio);
        btnViewVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewVideo);
        btnVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {

                    setDataSourc(datavideo);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnAudio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                    setDataSource(datamusic);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        btnViewVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(VideoPlayerActivity.this,
                        PlayingVideo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setDataSource(String path) throws IOException {

        // HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
        // HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        // HttpEntity cn = response.getEntity();

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();

        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();// getContent();
        if (stream == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        }
        mPath = new File(datamusic);
        mPath.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mPath);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
        do {
            int numRead = stream.read(buf);
            if (numRead <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        } while (true);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String sDummy = ex.toString();
            System.out.println("hello dummy" + sDummy);

        }
    }

    private void setDataSourc(String path) throws IOException {

        // HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
        // HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        // HttpEntity cn = response.getEntity();

        URL url = new URL(urlVodeo);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();

        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();// getContent();
        if (stream == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        }
        mPath = new File(datavideo);
        mPath.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mPath);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
        do {
            int numRead = stream.read(buf);
            if (numRead <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        } while (true);
        // mp = new MediaPlayer();
        // mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            // mp.setDataSource(path);
            // mp.prepare();
            // mp.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String sDummy = ex.toString();
            System.out.println("hello dummy" + sDummy);

        }
    }

}
```

I had used the above code in my application to solve the problem,may this help you.